# Bootstrap multiple cols not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

So, when I type multiple cols for my imgs tags only the md one is working.
Thats how its structured:[image]

And thats how the lg screen is looking like:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of columns must be 12 in each row class.also use img-responsive class for image.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Please check this codepan 
    codepen.io/payalpatel2299/pen/dOaLgd

Comment: the thing is, how to do it then since the amount of lg,md,sm are different and need to be inside the same rows as lg?

Comment: Check the codepan again please. I have added clearfix div. you can use offset as well  http://codepen.io/payalpatel2299/pen/dOaLgd

Comment: A Bootstrap row can exceed 12 columns in a row. It's called column wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Between each `class="row"` the sum of segments should be 12. Please notice the following code...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I know... but and when I need to put an lg,md and sm size? For example 6 col-lg-2 and 3 col-md-4 ? They dont fit in the same row...

Comment: Develop for `sm`. Get rid of `md` and `lg` and try your code in all resolutions with just `sm`.